# Powermaps / VBA / c#/ command line?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba

I have a question regarding **PowerMaps** and **VBA/C#**  or **Command Line**.
Is there any possibility to control *PowerMaps* via *VBA* or *C#* ?

I read **MSDN** articles but I didn't find any documentation about this tool.
I recorded a `macro` to find out any classes in VBA but Excel is not recording anything.. `:\`

Maybe I can start a `powermaps.exe` with a command line to an excel file but I didn't find an exe file `:(`

So, does anyone have an idea? I only want to show data in this tool programmatically.